# Select/copy hover text in R plotly graph

Tags: r, hover, plotly

I would like to be able to select and copy the hover text in plotly graphs. Is that possible with the R API?
For example, in [this heatmap](https://plot.ly/r/heatmaps/#categorical-axes), upon mousing over coordinates (X=a, Y=d), one can see the hover text displaying:

x=a,

y=d,

z=0.71886

However, the text is not selectable. The goal would be to *e.g.* display this text inside a box (perhaps by right-clicking on the corresponding cell) to be able to copy the text contents into the clipboard.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One way would involve using Shiny. See https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-hover-events/.

`event_data()` will allow you to retrieve values and then you can do things like show it inside a box or do some other computations etc

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. I will look into this